# Do "On Critical Strike" effects continue to chain off of each other?

Tags: dnd-4e, barbarian, critical-hit

I'm currently playing an epic level barbarian. I have a number of abilities that allow me to attack as a free action after I critically hit someone. I've even gone to the length of making a flow chart in order to reduce the time my turn takes when I critically hit.

The question I have, is if I critically hit on one of the free attacks granted from my critical hit, do I then get to start my flow chart over again?

Many of the abilities are gained from my paragon, class, and epic destinies. They do not require minor actions, and many of them don't specify if they take an action at all.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**No.**

You can only use a free action to attack once per round; from the *[Player's Handbook Update](http://www.wizards.com/dnd/Article.aspx?x=dnd/updatesarchive)* PDF (pg 19):

> Free Actions
>   Page 267: Replace the “Free Actions” bullet in the 
>   “The Main Action Types” section with the following 
>   text. This update limits the power of builds that capitalize 
>   on recursive attack power combinations.
>
> > ✦  Free Action: Free actions take almost no time or 
> >     effort. You can take as many free actions as you 
> >     want during your or another combatant’s turn. 
> >     There is an exception to that rule: A creature can 
> >     take a free action to use an attack power only once 
> >     per turn. ...

Answer (score 6):

Assuming that there are no other criteria on the attacks, and that the power haven't been errataed, yes.

Common restrictions:

- Extra attack is an immediate action (no more than once per full round, not on your turn).
- Extra attack is an opportunity action (no more than once per combatant's turn, not on your turn).
- Extra attack is a free action (no more than one free action attack per round).
- Extra attack triggers only on specific types of attacks (e.g. Barbarian powers, or basic attacks) (only triggers for the appropriate type of attack).

Comment: Something I haven't been looking at is the critical strike with a barbarian power. A melee attack granted by a barbarian ability isn't strictly a barbarian power. Thank you.

Comment: Nitpick -- you can only use one free action attack per round, so a lot of the old barbarian chaining effects are no more. This is as of the May errata, I believe.

Comment: -1: not your fault, but the rules changed and this is no more correct.

Comment: @Zachiel Could you include a reference to *how* the rules have changed?